# Trying To Uninstall Exchange 2007 From Server - Stuck On "Mailbox Role Checks"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2007

I am trying to uninstall Exchange 2007 on a secodary server which has been decommissioned for quite a while (cleaning up after an old Network Admin). The only roll the server had was "Mailbox Role" (the primary server also has this). I have tried uninstalling using Programs and Features GUI tool but that hung on Mailbox Role Checks.

I then tried uninstalling Exchange by running Setup.com /mode:uninstall. It has been stuck on 1% of "Mailbox Role Checks" for over 3 hours now.

Is there any other options I have for uninstalling Exchange 2007 so the old server can be removed from the Exchange Management console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just going into task manager and killing ever task possible until the removal process continued. The server has now been removed from the Exchange organization.